# Django "Add a related_name argument to the definition" Error

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
class BaseComment(models.Model):
    comment_author = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, related_name='written_comments')
    comment_content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    comment_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    users_voted = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name='voted_comments')

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['-comment_date']        

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.comment_author.email

class QuestionComment(BaseComment):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='comments')

class AnswerComment(BaseComment):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, related_name='comments')
```

This is my models.py. When I run syncdb, I get this error:

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:

app_quora.questioncomment: Accessor for field 'comment_author' clashes with rela
ted field 'MyUser.written_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the definiti
on for 'comment_author'.
app_quora.questioncomment: Reverse query name for field 'comment_author' clashes
 with related field 'MyUser.written_comments'. Add a related_name argument to th
e definition for 'comment_author'.
app_quora.questioncomment: Accessor for m2m field 'users_voted' clashes with rel
ated m2m field 'MyUser.voted_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the defin
ition for 'users_voted'.
app_quora.questioncomment: Reverse query name for m2m field 'users_voted' clashe
s with related m2m field 'MyUser.voted_comments'. Add a related_name argument to
 the definition for 'users_voted'.
app_quora.answercomment: Accessor for field 'comment_author' clashes with relate
d field 'MyUser.written_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the definition
 for 'comment_author'.
app_quora.answercomment: Reverse query name for field 'comment_author' clashes w
ith related field 'MyUser.written_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the 
definition for 'comment_author'.
app_quora.answercomment: Accessor for m2m field 'users_voted' clashes with relat
ed m2m field 'MyUser.voted_comments'. Add a related_name argument to the definit
ion for 'users_voted'.
app_quora.answercomment: Reverse query name for m2m field 'users_voted' clashes 
with related m2m field 'MyUser.voted_comments'. Add a related_name argument to t
he definition for 'users_voted'.
```

Well, the error tells me to add the "related_name" for both "comment_author" and "users_voted", which I ALREADY DID!!. I looked up similar questions on stackoverflow, but usually the issue was that people didn't have this "related_name" for clashing fields.

I added this fields, but am still getting this error... Can someone explain why?

Thanks :(((

Answer (score 3):

The problem you are seeing is because of the `ForeignKey` and `ManyToManyField` fields in the `BaseComment` model. Because it is an abstract model, django does not create a table for it.

However, the derived models `QuestionComment` and `AnswerComment` which inherit the fields try to add the same fields defined by `related_name` (`written_comments` , `voted_comments` ) in the `MyUser` model. Because you can have only one field with the same name it gives you those errors.

A solution would be to not have `BaseComment` as an abstract model and let it have its own table/model.

Or, you could add these fields in derived models.

You can also try not specifying `related_name` and let django decide the names, but I'm not sure if this will work or not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Well,, adding the fields in each derived model gives me the same error, while making the BaseComment non-abstract does solve the problem. But I feel like the latter is not a good solution since it will add the same tables for BaseComment, QuestionComment, and AnswerComment. Wouldn't this create extra table rows which I'm never going to be using..?? (thus taking up extra memory)

Comment: @user2492270, Have you changed names when you added the fields in derived models? Use different names in each models. When using non-abstract model, fields for base are put into base models tables while fields for derived goes in its table, do duplicates. But in object of derived can directly refer to fields in base.